# linux pthread running in a loop for specified time (avoiding signals)

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, timer, pthreads

hello what i want do is:
thread (pthread.h) need to execute code in a while loop for some period of time that will be defined at run time
after that the thread will finish correctly the last loop and continue for some other work.
right now I am using signals: This is the loop

```
setTimer(sec);
while(flag)
{
   //do some work
}
// continue to run
```

and i use signal to call for function that will set flag to false:

```
void setTimer(int sec)
{
  struct sigaction sa;
  struct itimerval timer;

  memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (sa));
  sa.sa_handler = &alarm_end_of_loop; // this is the function to change flag to false
  sigaction (SIGVTALRM, &sa, NULL);

  timer.it_value.tv_sec = sec;
  timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;

  timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
  timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;


  setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL);
}

void alarm_end_of_loop()
{
flag = 0; //flag is global but only one thread will access it
}
```

My question is there a way to avoid using signals?

Comment: You can use a second thread [`nanosleep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) for the desired duration, and then update the flag. For signals, I'd use a realtime signal like `SIGRTMIN+0` (to reduce the possibility of losing a signal) and a [`sa_siginfo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) handler to verify the sender pid (`si_pid` field). Or you can just regularly check the wall-clock time as Stefan Weiser shows in his answer.

Comment: i liked the idea using other thread with `nanosleep()` , but i think i will go with stephan solution

Comment: I often use Stefan Weiser's approach, myself. I do sometimes use a separate thread to manage many timeouts, though; then the timeout thread just manages a binary min-heap of future timeouts, using `pthread_cond_timedwait()` to wait until the next timeout, or the condition variable (which is signaled when another thread adds a new timeout). It's pretty simple to implement, and quite efficient. But worth it only if you have multiple threads, multiple concurrent timeouts, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a timeout pattern.

```
double get_delta_time_to_now(const time_t timeout_time)
{
    time_t now;
    time(&now);
    return difftime(now, timeout_time);
}

void do_it(int sec)
{
    time_t timeout_time;
    double diff;

    time(&timeout_time);
    timeout_time += sec; /* this is not necessarily correct */

    diff = get_delta_time_to_now(timeout_time);
    while (diff <= 0.0)
    {
        /* do your stuff */

        diff = get_delta_time_to_now(timeout_time);
    }
}
```